# Webgl: Why no gl.multiDrawElements?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, gl-triangle-strip

Why is there no version of [glMultiDrawElements](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glMultiDrawElements.xml)  for webgl?

It seems like such a useful function, especially when drawing a large number of `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`S or `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN`s.

Is there a specific reason this function was left out?

Comment: Simplicity I guess? Even the docs say: _"glMultiDrawElements is identical in operation to glDrawElements except that drawcount separate lists of elements are specified."_.

Comment: WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0; OpenGL ES consciously stripped OpenGL down to its bare essentials. `glMultiDrawArrays` and `glMultiDrawElements` are essentially nothing more than additions to the OpenGL (1.4) to reduce the number of API calls. Since the same thing can be achieved using multiple back-to-back draw calls, you can see why it is not a good fit for ES. It is very much like RISC vs. CISC in the CPU architecture world, simpler is better particularly in embedded applications.

Comment: Except that multiple gpu commands are usually bad due to the cpu->gpu bottleneck.  is this not as much of an issue on mobile SoCs?
I just tested on a windows PC and MultiDrawArrays is about 30% faster than a loop of DrawArrays.  (drawing 100k 12tri boxes)